# Invalid command 'WSGIScriptAlias', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration

Tags: django, apache, wsgi, raspbian

I am trying to set up a Django server for production. In my browser, if I type in the IP address that corresponds to my server, I get the default Apache page "It works!" instead of a Django-related page.

I have modified httpd.conf to include the line:

```
WSGIScriptAlias / /var/the-1/django/The1/apache/django.wsgi
```

And I created the actual file django.wsgi, which looks like:

```
import os
import sys

path = '/var/the-1/django/The1'
if path not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(path)

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'The1.settings'

import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

But when I restart the server, I receive the error:

```
AH00526: Syntax error on line 506 of /usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf:
Invalid command 'WSGIScriptAlias', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
```

when I try to restart Apache using:

```
/usr/local/apache2/bin/apachectl -k restart
```

However, if I use the command:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

I don't receive the error (though I think they're not really doing the same thing).

If I run apache2ctl -M, the following two lines appear (among others):

```
alias_module (shared)
wsgi_module (shared)
```

so I believe those modules are running correctly.

I have already tried completely uninstalling and reinstalling libapache2-mod-wsgi. The server I am working on is a Raspberry Pi running Raspbian. This is my first time setting up a server, so I know very little about Apache or how to set up Django.

**EDIT**: Below is my httpd.conf file (note that because the actual file is so long, I have removed all comments):

```
ServerRoot "/usr/local/apache2"

Listen 80

LoadModule authn_file_module modules/mod_authn_file.so
LoadModule authn_core_module modules/mod_authn_core.so
LoadModule authz_host_module modules/mod_authz_host.so
LoadModule authz_groupfile_module modules/mod_authz_groupfile.so
LoadModule authz_user_module modules/mod_authz_user.so
LoadModule authz_core_module modules/mod_authz_core.so
LoadModule access_compat_module modules/mod_access_compat.so
LoadModule auth_basic_module modules/mod_auth_basic.so
LoadModule reqtimeout_module modules/mod_reqtimeout.so
LoadModule filter_module modules/mod_filter.so
LoadModule mime_module modules/mod_mime.so
LoadModule log_config_module modules/mod_log_config.so
LoadModule env_module modules/mod_env.so
LoadModule headers_module modules/mod_headers.so
LoadModule setenvif_module modules/mod_setenvif.so
LoadModule version_module modules/mod_version.so
LoadModule unixd_module modules/mod_unixd.so
LoadModule status_module modules/mod_status.so
LoadModule autoindex_module modules/mod_autoindex.so
LoadModule dir_module modules/mod_dir.so
LoadModule alias_module modules/mod_alias.so
LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so

<IfModule unixd_module>
User daemon
Group daemon
</IfModule>

ServerAdmin you@example.com
ServerName [SERVER_IP_ADDRESS]:80 # Removed for security reasons

#<Directory />
#    AllowOverride none
#    Require all denied
#</Directory>

DocumentRoot "/usr/local/apache2/htdocs"
<Directory "/usr/local/apache2/htdocs">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.html
</IfModule>

<Files ".ht*">
    Require all denied
</Files>

ErrorLog "logs/error_log"

LogLevel warn

<IfModule log_config_module>
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common
    <IfModule logio_module>
      LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" %I %O" combinedio
    </IfModule>
    CustomLog "logs/access_log" common
</IfModule>

<IfModule alias_module>
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "/usr/local/apache2/cgi-bin/"
</IfModule>

<IfModule cgid_module>
</IfModule>

<Directory "/usr/local/apache2/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<IfModule mime_module>
        TypesConfig conf/mime.types
    AddType application/x-compress .Z
    AddType application/x-gzip .gz .tgz
</IfModule>

<IfModule proxy_html_module>
Include conf/extra/proxy-html.conf
</IfModule>

<IfModule ssl_module>
SSLRandomSeed startup builtin
SSLRandomSeed connect builtin
</IfModule>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName [SERVER_IP_ADDRESS]:80 # Removed for security reasons
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/the-1/django/The1/apache/django.wsgi
    <Directory /var/the-1/django/The1/apache>
        ###<Files django.wsgi>
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
        ###</Files>
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

**EDIT 2 (Solution)**: There were some problems with my above config file. I was missing a LoadModule line for mod_wsgi.so and I also had to comment out one of the  sections. The comments in the first solution go through it a bit.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

First you might want to check the config using

```
/etc/init.d/httpd configtest
```

or 
    sudo apache2ctl -t

and also check if the module is enabled.

```
sudo a2enmod wsgi
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. My directory /etc/init.d/ does not contain a file httpd, perhaps my installation of apache is wrong? I think I installed apache under /usr/local/apache2 though.
However, sudo apache2ctl -t returns "Syntax OK" and sudo a2enmod wsgi returns "Module wsgi already enabled".

Comment: If these are fine, can you please share your Apache config ? 
and also can you try restarting by explicitly providing the path to config file (use -f option on apachectl )?

Comment: "sudo /usr/local/apache2/bin/apachectl -f /usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf -k restart" results in the exact same error. I have included my httpd.conf file for reference (with all comments removed).

Comment: You know what? When I just posted the httpd.conf file with the comments removed, I noticed that mod_wsgi.so wasn't imported. I'm looking into that now...

Comment: Yes, now Apache restarts without any errors. :) Now I am just trying to figure out why Apache throws a 403 Forbidden error when I try to request directory /, which is aliased to /var/the-1/django/The1/apache/django.wsgi (I updated the config file above).

Comment: That is some progress, if it 403 then might be your wsgi script. and also try running manage.py runserver

Comment: I got it working! :D My second problem was that earlier in the httpd.conf file, there was a <Directory> section that blocked access to '/', which was overriding the later one. I just commented that out and voila!

Comment: I didnt' have WSGI installed: 
On python2: sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-wsgi
On python3: sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3